# Is using “NOT EXISTS” considered to be bad SQL practise?

Tags: sql, coding-style

I have heard a lot of people over the years say that:

> "join" operators are preferred over “NOT EXISTS”

Why?

Comment: Why is this closed? I am curious about the reason too.

Comment: @Ziayo: probably because of the words "lot of people". If worded "are joins more efficient than `NOT EXISTS`", that would be a perfect question answerable with "facts, references, or specific expertise".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `MySQL`, `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL`, `NOT EXISTS` is of the same efficiency or even more efficient than `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`.

While it may seem that "the inner query should be executed for each record from the outer query" (which seems to be bad for `NOT EXISTS` and even worse for `NOT IN`, since the latter query is not even correlated), it may be optimized just as well as all other queries are optimized, using appropriate `anti-join` methods.

In `SQL Server`, actually, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` may be less efficient than `NOT EXISTS / NOT IN` in case of unindexed or low cardinality column in the inner table.

It is often heard that `MySQL` is "especially bad in treating subqueries".

This roots from the fact that `MySQL` is not capable of any join methods other than nested loops, which severely limits its optimization abilities.

The only case when a query would benefit from rewriting subquery as a join would be this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    big_table
WHERE   big_table_column IN
        (
        SELECT  small_table_column
        FROM    small_table
        )
```

`small_table` will not be queried completely for each record in `big_table`: though it does not seem to be correlated, it will be implicitly correlated by the query optimizer and in fact rewritten to an `EXISTS` (using `index_subquery` to search for the first much if needed if `small_table_column` is indexed)

But `big_table` would always be leading, which makes the query complete in `big * LOG(small)` rather than `small * LOG(big)` reads.

This could be rewritten as

```
SELECT  DISTINCT bt.*
FROM    small_table st
JOIN    big_table bt
ON      bt.big_table_column = st.small_table_column
```

However, this won't improve `NOT IN` (as opposed to `IN`). In `MySQL`, `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` are almost the same, since with nested loops the left table should always be leading in a `LEFT JOIN`.

You may want to read these articles:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)
- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: PostgreSQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/)
- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: Oracle**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/)
- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)
- [**IN vs. JOIN vs. EXISTS: Oracle**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/30/in-vs-join-vs-exists-oracle/)
- [**IN vs. JOIN vs. EXISTS**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/) **(SQL Server)**

Comment: For how long has this been the case?

Comment: @Qnassnoi, that the efficiency is about the same

Comment: @Ian: for `Oracle` and `SQL Server`, at least since I'm in the industry (1997).

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the optimization process... NOT EXISTS implies a subquery, and "optimizers" usually don't do subqueries justice. On the other hand, joins can be dealt with more easily...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a MySQL specific case. MySQL do not optimize subquery in IN / not in / any / not exists clauses, and actually performs the subquery for each row matched by the outer query. Because of this in MySQL, you should use join. In PostgreSQL however, you can just use subquery.

Comment: It does optimize all these clauses. Please read http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @Darhazer, you seem stuck in MySQL version 4.

Comment: @Johan: ... which also optimized all these constructs.

Comment: I'm wrong for exists/not exists queries. But IN subqueries often are slow because of the reason described above. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/

Comment: "often are slow" and "does not optimize" are different things. `IN` subqueries are optimized (i. e. the inner query is not performed verbatim for each outer row), though not correctly if the `IN` table is small and the outer table is large. However, `NOT IN` and `IN` are completely different things, both logically and in terms of execution.

Comment: Thank you for the link provided and for the explanations.