# SQL Query on 3 tables

Tags: sql

I've got three tables:

Galaxies, solar Systems and Planets.

All of them are connected by Id's in an obvious way (Galaxies may have xx Solar Systems, SS can have xx planets). Let's say they have such structure:

```
    Galaxy: id, name
    Solar System: id, id_galaxy, name
    Planet: id, id_solar_system, name
```

I'm really struggling with creating a query to do the following:

**Select names of galaxies that do not have planets at all**. (They can still have empty Solar systems).

Please ignore the fact that something may seem unlikely science-wise ;)

I figured it must be something with left outer join, I can easily select Solar Systems that do not have any planets, but I seem to struggle to "propagate' it to Galaxies. I think I need some more complex query here, maybe a subquery).

Please help, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you tell us what RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `having` clause:

```
SELECT G.id, G.name
FROM Galaxy G LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SolarSystem SS
     ON G.id = SS.id_galaxy LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Planet P
     ON SS.id = P.id_solar_system
group by g_id, g.name
having max(P.id) IS NULL
```

The `left outer join`s bring together all planets and solar systems.  The `having` clause chooses the ones that have no planets at all in the galazy.

Comment: +1 - I have no idea what I was thinking with my query, other than "I wasn't"

Comment: Thank you very much man! Works just as it needed to. The world needs more people like you.

Answer (score 3):

I find using `not exists` the most readable for this sort of problem:

```sql
select name
from galaxy g
where not exists( select * 
                  from solarsystem s join planet p on s.id=p.id_solar_system
                  where id_galaxy=g.id )
```

Comment: More readable and maybe more efficient that a GROUP BY solution.

Comment: Or perhaps *much less efficient*.  It depends very much on the SQL engine.  `Not exist` is often slow, and correlated queries often do not  run in parallel.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed. On Oracle, postgres and newer versions of SQL Server this will be transformed into an anti-join that will perform well, but whether the same is true on MySQL et al. I have no idea. This answer lists more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778017/533832