# Selecting Rows Based on Max Column in Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a high score board for a video game.

There is a `users` table:

[image]

And a `scores` table:

[image]

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(`scores`.`score`) AS max_score,
    `scores`.`team`,
    `users`.`name`
FROM `scores`
    LEFT JOIN `users`
    ON `users`.`id` = `scores`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `scores`.`user_id`
ORDER BY max_score DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Which returns this result (sample):

[image]

As you can see, user `FUNTIMES`'s score of `210` is being attributed to the `eagles` when it should be attributed to the `vikings` according to the `scores` table (`FUNTIMES`'s `user_id` is 11).

How would I go about fixing this?  Something like this would work beautifully:

```
SELECT `scores`.`score`, `scores`.`team`, `users`.`name`
FROM `scores`
LEFT JOIN `users`
ON `users`.`id` = `scores`.`user_id`
WHERE `scores`.`id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`scores`.`score`)
    FROM `scores`
    GROUP BY `scores`.`user_id`
)
ORDER BY `scores`.`score` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

but, of course, I can't select WHERE `id` is IN `score`.  I'm completely lost.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:  Sorry, I forgot to mention:  Each user can only be displayed once in the high scores table.  (This is why I have the GROUP BY `user_id` stipulation in my query.)

Comment: Are you only trying to show the 50 users with the highest scores of the 50 highest scores overall?  I guess I am not clear in real-world terms on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, each user should only be displayed once.  (No repeat users.)

Comment: So the problem is that a user might have scores under different team name and you want the team name under which there highest score was psoted?

Comment: There is no way to do this in a scalable way with a single query with Oracle's MySQL. Try Percona or MariaDB.

Comment: The problem is that the incorrect team is being attributed to the scores, as the aggregate functions (such as MAX() in this case) in MySQL do not keep the rows' columns in line, and pull columns from other rows than the MAX()'s target.

Comment: @Aron : I highly doubt that.  Look at AgRizzo's answer below, I think he got it.

Comment: @Leng I choose my words carefully. This will work with a small data set...but MySQL will use a Nested Inner Join, which an O(n^2) operation.

Comment: @Aron : I see.  Apologies, I see you're correct.

Comment: @Leng You can do it with a SPROC efficiently...But that is more than one query.

Comment: @Aron That's so crazy - how could something this simple be beyond the scalable capabilities of MySQL??  I'm flabbergasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT scores.score, scores.team, users.name
FROM users
JOIN scores
  ON users.id = scores.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM scores scores2
   WHERE scores2.score > scores.score
     AND scores2.user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: This will only return 1 row (of the single user with the highest score).

Comment: forgot to use the user.id

Comment: If you plan on using this query above a few hundred users read this first http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778017/1808494. Then uninstall Oracle MySQL and replace it with MariaDB (Open Source MySQL)

Comment: @Aron - would you say that Fabien's query suffers the same scalability issues?

Comment: @Aron Both MySQL and MariaDB are open source.

Comment: @Aron I'm confused. A project is considered open-source only if it  accepts contributions from anyone?

Comment: @ypercube Levels of grey. I don't concider MySQL as truly open source, and I am highly suspicious about the motives of Oracle in buying MySQL out. Given the highly limited feature set AND that several forks exist with those missing features, I believe Oracle are actively NOT developing MySQL. So I guess my gripe is not so much it isn't an Open Source project, but that it isn't even a project.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5efe/8)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(8), `pass` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO users 
    (`id`, `name`, `pass`)
VALUES
    (2, 'JAKE', 'jake'),
    (3, NULL, NULL),
    (4, 'AWNO', 'ffff'),
    (5, 'FFF', 'ffff'),
    (6, 'ASDF', 'asdf'),
    (7, 'KKK', 'kkkk'),
    (8, 'AW YEAH', 'good'),
    (9, 'FFFF', 'ffff'),
    (10, 'FUNTIME', 'llll'),
    (11, 'FUNTIMES', 'llll'),
    (12, 'GOOD', 'good')
;

CREATE TABLE scores
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `team` varchar(7), `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO scores
    (`id`, `user_id`, `team`, `score`)
VALUES
    (32, 9, 'vikings', 610),
    (33, 10, 'eagles', 290),
    (34, 11, 'eagles', 0),
    (35, 11, 'vikings', 40),
    (36, 11, 'vikings', 210),
    (37, 12, 'eagles', 170),
    (38, 12, 'eagles', 30)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT m.`max_score`,
    s.`team`,
    u.`name`
FROM `scores` s
    LEFT JOIN `users` u
    ON u.`id` = s.`user_id`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`score`) as max_score 
            FROM `scores` 
            GROUP BY `user_id`) m ON m.`user_id` = s.`user_id` AND
                                     m.`max_score` = s.`score`
ORDER BY max_score DESC
LIMIT 50
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5efe/8/0)**:

```
| MAX_SCORE |    TEAM |     NAME |
|-----------|---------|----------|
|       610 | vikings |     FFFF |
|       290 |  eagles |  FUNTIME |
|       210 | vikings | FUNTIMES |
|       170 |  eagles |     GOOD |
```

FOR DISCUSSION PURPOSE :

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`score`) as max_score 
            FROM `scores` 
            GROUP BY `user_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5efe/7/0)**:

```
| USER_ID | MAX_SCORE |
|---------|-----------|
|       9 |       610 |
|      10 |       290 |
|      11 |       210 |
|      12 |       170 |
```

Comment: This will, unfortunately, allow the same user to make the high scores table multiple times, which I can't allow.  (Sorry I didn't specify this in my question, let me edit it real quick.)

Comment: I apologize for not having created a SQL fiddle for this question and for having not specified that I needed each user one time only!  Your query does indeed now work.  I have upvoted it and would love to green-check it as well, but I just gave the check to AgRizzo for his (also correct) answer moments before your edit!  Apologies and thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Actually, your query will not always work.  You're using this in your subquery:  `SELECT user_id, MAX(score) as max_score` -- the `user_id` column will not always be pulled from the same row as the `MAX(score)` because that's not how aggregate functions work in MySQL (which is why my query in my question doesn't work).  Please let me know if I'm wrong?

Comment: It works...that give the max score for every user id. See the bottom of my answer...

Comment: I see now - how very odd!  I wonder why it'd always return the correct user_id where it only would -sometimes- return the correct team if you included team in your SELECT like this:  SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`score`) as max_score, `team` ?

Comment: these indexes http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cad00a/2 will make sure the MySQL server doesn't going to create an large MyISAM disk based temp table that needs to be sorted with disk IO reads and writes when the tables are very large

Comment: @RaymondNijland The `CREATE TABLE` in SQLFIDDLE is only for demonstration of the query. Of course indexes are needed :)

Comment: @Fabien TheSolution i know your anwser is correct so i've voted up.. mine comment was just extra information

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

UPDATE result SET max_score = (SELECT SUM(score) FROM scores WHERE users.id=scores.user_id), team = (SELECT team FROM scores WHERE scores.user_id=users.id), name = (SELECT name FROM users WHERE users.id=scores.user_id) LIMIT 50;